# SVN: 404 Error when trying to revert to previous revision

Tags: svn, apache2, tortoisesvn, debian, revert

Some time ago I set up a debian svn server and so far it works without any problems.

Yesterday I had some trouble with commiting some changes and wanted to revert to a revision some revisions ago, but this didn't work. This was the first time I tried this, so I don't know if it worked at any time.

I managed to solve the commiting-issue but still can't revert. I can revert recent changes, but when i want to go some revisions back I get a 404 error.

I'm using Tortoise in client side and could not find any information to this issue.

Does anybody know this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

*Additional information:*

SVN-Client: 1.8.1

SVN-Server: 1.6.17

The committing-trouble I mentioned was that I couldn't commit because I always got a "out of date" error, even if the affected files were new. I solved it by making a backup of parent Directory and then deleted it, then updated and commited, then re-added directory and committed again.

The exact error I get when I try to revert some revisions back is:

> Repository moved temporarily to
>   'https://url.ofmyserver.com/errors/404.html'; please relocate

Comment: The issue you describe is unclear. What SVN version you have installed on client and server? What errors do you get? What kind of commiting trouble do you mean?

Comment: Do you really see URL as you've specified it? It makes sense to check the server side (Apache HTTP Server that serves Subversion repos via HTTPS) because it errors-out with 404 (not found). Make sure you use correct URLs. It's very hard to tell what's the issue here.

Comment: @bahrep: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is the exact output (of course except of the domain name). Unfortunately I don't know what to check on server side. I know for sure that I use the correct repository URL and repository has never moved. I don't know the internal workflow of svn (what url it uses to get back to a specific revision). However it's very strange that server doesn't find it because this doesn't seem like a configuration issue (since it's just possible to set URL of repository, not of a single revision).

Comment: This moment I realized that i can't even create a branch due to the same issue. This is a really big problem and I've got no idea how to solve this! Please help me! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of desperation and nearly getting crazy I managed to solve the problem!!

The reason were some misconfirurations in .htaccess: I used absolute URLs for my ErrorDocs. I really don't know why this can cause this kind of trouble, but it actually did.